# After yum update is it a good idea to restart the server?

Tags: yum

I'm aware that it is good to run `yum update` from time to time to keep my Centos server updated, and I even see that there is way to [automate this update](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-updating-your-system.html#sn-automatic-updating).  My question is, is it necessary to restart the server after the update? Is it a good idea? What happens if I keep updating and never restart?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't have to restart the server unless you are getting a message (from yum) that explicitly encourages you to do so.

But you can't use the new kernel that was updated until you restart the system (unless you are using something like [Ksplice](http://www.ksplice.com/), which is a technology that switches the old kernel with the new one without the need for a reboot).

So in the end, it's your decision if you want to reboot. I would suggest that unless there's a major security update for the kernel you shouldn't reboot during work hours. Otherwise, if the server is idle (and you don't need it for the next 30 minutes or so, because in some rare circumstances updates could interfere with the boot process), I would suggest you reboot it.

Answer (score 11):

If kernel has updated, yes it is a good idea to reboot because new kernel will be used only after reboot. other packages will be updated in place, no need to reboot.

Comment: updates to libc without reboot can give issues

Comment: that is not correct, there are a number of other packages that require a reboot to be updated correctly, as pointed out above libc is one, there are others (systemd/init)

Comment: To say it more clean than Folkert: You should also reboot after a glibc update.

Comment: @Nils You don't need to reboot; it's enough to restart all the services which you want to switch to run against the new libc.

Comment: @Gilles true, but is there a way to easily sort out which (running) services are affected in RH?

Comment: @Nils On most systems, all services are linked against libc. There's no automatic way to know which ones must be restarted: only the ones that are affected by whatever bug the upgrade fixes are important.

Comment: @Gilles SLES11 SP1 seems to have such a mechanism. After a patch-install a zypper command shows the affected services. I did not debug how it is being done...

Comment: @Nils I think it's like Debian: the library package upgrade script checks which services are installed and linked against the library.

Comment: If the kernel, libc, glibc is updated, do I really NEED to restart the server, if I don't restart the server, will it keep working correctly?

Answer (score 8):

I have a fully automated server that gets its daily updates via `yum-cron` and I let it reboot every weekend (via root-crontab).

This has been working well for more than three years now.

Comment: I like this solution.

Comment: where did you get yum-cron for Windows?

Comment: @Mary That is a feature of Windows 12.

Answer (score 0):

I don't trust the auto-updates, as any update has the potential to disable a service. I do them manually on the servers, and if kernel or glib is involved, I reboot the server afterwards.